# Extracting Guest List from Google Calendar

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, calendar

I am trying to extract information from a group Google Calendar. I can pull the title, description, start and end date & duration but I am not able to work out the code to pull the guest list (I would like to pull all guests not just those who have responded to the invite).

Here is my code so far:

```
function importGoogleCalendar() { 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var calendarId = sheet.getRange('B1').getValue().toString(); 
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
 
  // Set filters
  var startDate = sheet.getRange('B2').getValue();
  var endDate = sheet.getRange('B3').getValue();
  var searchText = sheet.getRange('B4').getValue();
 
  // Print header
  var header = [["Title", "Description", "Start", "End", "Duration", "Guests"]];
  var range = sheet.getRange("A6:F6");
  range.setValues(header);
  range.setFontWeight("bold")

  // Get events based on filters
  var events = (searchText == '') ? calendar.getEvents(startDate, endDate) : calendar.getEvents(startDate, endDate, {search: searchText});
 
  // Display events 
  for (var i=0; i<events.length; i++) {
    var row = i+7;
    
    var details = [[events[i].getTitle(), events[i].getDescription(), events[i].getStartTime(), events[i].getEndTime(), events[i].getNames()]];
    
    range = sheet.getRange(row,1,1,5);
    range.setValues(details);
 
    // Format the Start and End columns
    var cell = sheet.getRange(row, 3);
    cell.setNumberFormat('mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm');
    cell = sheet.getRange(row, 4);
    cell.setNumberFormat('mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm');
 
    // Fill the Duration column
    cell = sheet.getRange(row, 5);
    cell.setFormula('=(HOUR(D' + row + ')+(MINUTE(D' +row+ ')/60))-(HOUR(C' +row+ ')+(MINUTE(C' +row+ ')/60))');
    cell.setNumberFormat('0.00');
  }
}
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can make this work??

Thanks!!